# Using ArcPy to Raster clip extent to be same as display?

Tags: arcpy, raster, extents

I've been trying to figure this out for almost a week now. I am creating a tool which first needs the raster to be clipped out to the current display. I have tried all sorts of things. Below is the current code I've been trying to get working. You can also see the previous code commented out.

```
import arcpy
view = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument.activeView
#view = arcpy.env.extent

# Local variables:
inputRaster = "D:\bt_gis\Contours\InstaContours\LA_OC_DEMs.img"
outputRaster = "C:\\Users\\JZimmer\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb\\LA_OC_DEMs_Clip2.img"

# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_management(inputRaster, view, outputRaster, "", "-3.402823e+038", "NONE")
#arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management (inputRaster, outputRaster, "", view, "")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the current visible view you should be using [activeView.Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extent_Property/0012000001mz000000/). This will return an Envelope which can be used as an input into the Clip tool.

> The Extent property holds the visible area of the view.  The Extent is automatically captured whenever the view's transformation changes.  For example, when the active view is a Map, the Extent is modified whenever the spatial reference changes.  Also, the Extent is set the first time a layer is added to a Map.  In layout view, the Extent is initially set to the page size.  In both layout view and data view, zooming in our out changes the Extent.

Try this:

```
view = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument.activeView.Extent
```

Answer (score 1):

Although slightly beyond the scope of the OP's question, to constrain the footprint of the general raster processing environment to the view (extending from @Radar's suggestion):
`arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument.activeView.Extent`. `Clip_management()` wouldn't use this, but lots of other functions (particularly map algebra stuff) will.